# How to correctly mock and test for async method call

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio, python-mock

I have a `Server` class that is responsible for spinning up an `asyncio` loop. A simplified outline is present in the code example below.

I am writing a test (with `pytest`) to mock and ensure that the Server calls a specific method when it starts to `run`. The test succeeds, but I get a Runtime warning that the mock was never awaited.

```
test_async_func_call.py::test_that_poll_is_called
  /Users/subhashb/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py:80: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncMockMixin._execute_mock_call' was never awaited
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
```

**What is the correct way to test the method call?** I could avoid this entirely and write an integration test, but I am curious to understand how to await a mock.

Code example:

```py
import asyncio

from mock import patch


class Server:
    def __init__(self, test_mode=False):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.test_mode = test_mode

    async def poll(self):
        print("Polling...")
        self.loop.call_later(0.5, self.poll)

    def run(self):
        self.loop.call_soon(self.poll)

        if self.test_mode:
            self.loop.call_soon(self.loop.stop)

        self.loop.run_forever()


@patch.object(Server, "poll")
def test_that_poll_is_called(mock):
    Server(test_mode=True).run()

    mock.assert_called_once()
```